# Party Handshakes

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[Where i got this question from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3vXr.jpg)

Question basically states that in a party with n+1 couples who might have shaken hands, the host asks the remaining 2n+1 people how many hands they shook and gets 2n+1 different answers. How many hands did the host shake?

So, my first approach to this question was to use pigeonhole principle and since 2n+1 and 0 handshakes can be put in the same hole, the answer is **n**.

However the question explicitly states solving it using induction. Any help on what to use for the induction step? As if we add another couple, they would shake hands with many people raising the numbers of the people whoso hands were shook previously.

Comment: How did you conclude that the answer must be $n$? Also note that given the question,  no one shook $2n+1$ hands. Also it seems the question is about the host wife, which completely losts me.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your proof that the answer is $n$, even if it doesn't use induction.  What you sketched is not clear.

Comment: @lulu I'm starting to have a doubt for $n$. Isn't there a big problem if it is odd?

Comment: @Qise  I expect the logic is to argue, inductively, that for each guest, the sum of the number of hands shaken plus the number of the hands shaken by the guest's spouse must be $2n$.  For instance, the unique person who shook $2n$ hands must be married to the unique person who shook $0$ (after all, there is a $0-$person and it clearly can't be anyone besides the spouse as the other all shook hands with the $2n-$person at least).   Deleting the $(2n,0)$ couple from the party yields the same problem with $n-1$ guest couples, hence the induction step.

Comment: @lulu my guess is also that the answer is $2n$ or 0. I don't see how any other answer can be reached via induction.

Comment: @Qise  Try it with $n=1$.  If If the Hostess shakes hands with both guests, then there can't be a $0-$guest.  If the Hostess shakes hands with neither guest, then there can't be a $2-$guest.  Thus, the Hostess shakes hands with exactly $1$ guest.  Same for the Host, of course.

Comment: @Qise  But, really, the inductive proof I sketched works.  It needs to be fleshed out, of course, but I don't think there's anything wrong with it.

Comment: @D.S.  Of course the hostess may shake hands!  The host needs to get $2n+1$ different responses, and one of those responses must be from the hostess.  And I sketched a quick argument earlier which shows where induction enters.

Comment: I don't see any indication that the pigeonhole principle can be applied in any way. And @DS: Why can the guests only shake hands with $2n-1$ people? Any guest can shake hands with the host, the hostess and both people in the $n-1$ other couples, giving a total of $2n$ people?

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity because we assume the host does not shake hands with anyone

Comment: @DS: That would do it, I missed that part in the comments making this answerable.

Comment: @DS It is clear that the host most be included in the handshaking, for if not then there would have been someone who shook hands with $2n$ people... They themselves are not included, by your assumption the host not included, and per the problem statement their spouse not included... which is impossible as there are only $2n-1$ valid targets at that point for them to shake hands with they could not have achieved a full $2n$ handshakes.

Comment: @DS "*if the host shakes hands, then any answer can be true*"  No, the only possibility is $n$.  Other answers are impossible.

Comment: @JMoravitz I agree that my previous reasoning was faulted. I had thought about it superficially. But after reading your answer, I understand it better

Answer (score 1):

The punchline at the end of the day is that since all answers were different, the answers must have been $0,1,2,\dots,2n$.  Note that $2n+1$ is not possible since that would have required the person who shook hands with $2n+1$ people to have shaken hands with everyone different than themself and that would have included their spouse which is forbidden by the problem statement.

Now... the person who shook hands with $2n$ other people must have been married to the person who shook zero hands.  Otherwise, that person who shook zero hands would have necessarily been one of the other people and would have thus needed to have been one of the $2n$ valid people available for the person who shook $2n$ hands to shake hands with.

Since the person who shook $2n$ hands is a couple with the person who shook $0$ hands, we can effectively ignore them as we continue on.

We repeat the same line of logic to find that the person who shook hands with $2n-1$ people must be coupled with the person who shook $1$ hand.  We continue in this way finding the person who shook $2n-2$ is coupled with the person who shook $2$ and so on, the person who shook $2n-k$ hands is coupled with the person who shook $k$ hands.

We make it to the end where we find the person who shook $2n-n$ hands must be coupled with the person who shook $n$ hands.  However, we note that $2n-n = n$ and so these two hypothetical people would have given the same answer had they both been asked how many hands they shook.

The resolution to this, is that one of these two people must not have been asked the question.  In other words, one of these two people must have been the host.  The host must therefore have shaken $n$ hands.  The hostess then must also have shaken $n$ hands.

---

I personally feel as though phrasing it in this way is sufficient as a direct proof, and that induction is not strictly necessary.